# NSString  (with method call : stringWithContentsOfFile)

Tags: iphone, cocoa

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass : [self class]];
NSString *f_path = nil;

if ((f_path = [bundle pathForResource : @"about_screen" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"html"]) != nil)
{                      
    NSLog(@" f_path found" );  
    NSString *ns_string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile : f_path
                                    encoding                 : NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                    error                    : NULL
                           ];
    NSLog(@" string = %@", ns_string);  
}
else
{
    NSLog(@" f_path not found" );

}

// *** if the following assignment is commented off, there will be an error. ***
ns_string =
@"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\"><HTML><HEAD><TITLE>minimal test </TITLE></HEAD><BODY bgcolor = \"silver\"><H1>Hi</H1><P>This is very minimal \"hello world\" test document.</P> </BODY></HTML>"; 


[web_view loadHTMLString : ns_string  baseURL : nil];
```

Consider the above code segment.

For testing purpose I have set the content of the file "about_screen.html" to be the same as the string assigned to ns_string in the code above.  So if "NSString stringWithContentsOfFile" works as expected, the ns_string "in-line" assignment can be commented off without making any difference.

My problem is : the in-line assignment works as expected but without it, there will be a run time error.

The error is :

> -[About_Screen dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6eddf70'

Also note that the statement :

> NSLog(@" string = %@", ns_string);

always outputs the correct string, so the embedded html file is found and is being read correctly.

Hope that somebody familiar with this could help.

Comment: From the code above, the variable ns_string would be out of scope when it is used for web_view.  Move it above the 'if' statement.  Is ns_string already defined above the 'if' statement?

Comment: You are right, @bbamhart, you have solved one of the my most perplexing problems. Thanks :)

Comment: Also, ns_string is already declared earlier (not shown).  So the compiler wouldn't complain about the last ns_string assignment.

Comment: If it was already declared, then your declaration inside the `if` block shadows the outer variable.

Comment: Variable declarations within the same scope should be grouped together (which I had not done, serves as a good lesson ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer actually comes from @bbamhart's comment.  I thought the problem was due to the NSUTF8StringEncoding parameter since it shows up frequently from googling on related topics.

The real cause of the problem is about variable scope.  ns_string should not be declared in any conditional blocks.  (since the variable would then normally not be accessible outside the block.)

The bottom-line solution is simply move the declaration out of the block.